# Specification of nested random effects in lmer to account for pseudoreplicates

Tags: r

I have searched extensiely for random effects specification both here in SE and also http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq, but couldn't find the case that fitted my problem.
The data and a cartoon explaining my experimental design are [here](https://figshare.com/articles/Response_of_digestive_organs_of_Hypsiboas_albopunctatus_Anura_Hylidae_to_benzo_pyrene/4620736).

I have a fully-crossed 3x2 factorial design: one treatment with varying concentrations of a pollutant (factor with 3 levels) and another one with varying time of exposure (factor with two levels).
Each treatment had 5 animals (coded as a factor), which were given an injection with the pollutant and were killed after a given period of time (3 or 7 days) to remove the organ. The response variable is thickness of epithelium that was measured in 25 pictures of histological sections of the intestine per animal. This is summed up below:

```
           time                                 
           3d                 7d                
           animal             animal            
 treatment 1      2  3  4  5  1      2  3  4  5 
 1cont     25     25 25 25 25 25     25 25 25 25
 3mg       25     25 25 25 25 25     25 25 25 25
 7mg       25     25 25 25 25 25     25 25 25 25
```

**My question is: how do I specify the random factor to account for these pseudoreplicates (pictures) within each animal (replicate that received the treatment)?** Is this `(1|animal)`, which gives a random intercept to `animal`, already sufficient?

I started with `mod2` below that modelled intercept varying among animals and among pictures within animals. But I'm not sure if this is the most correct way. Then I tried other approaches including animals and treatments (treatment and time).

`mod1<-lmer(thickness~treatment*time+(1+treatment|animal)+(1+time|animal), data = intestine, REML=FALSE)
mod2<-lmer(thickness~treatment*time+(1|animal/photo), data = intestine, REML=FALSE)
mod3<-lmer(thickness~treatment*time+(1|animal), data = intestine, REML=FALSE)
mod4<-lmer(thickness~treatment*time+(animal|photo), data = intestine, REML=FALSE)
mod5<-lmer(thickness~treatment*time+(1|treatment:animal)+(1|time:animal), data = intestine, REML=FALSE)
mod6<-lmer(thickness~treatment*time+(1|animal)+(1|photo), data = intestine, REML=FALSE)`

But then I made a model selection, which showed `mod5` was the best

```
Model selection based on AICc:

      K    AICc Delta_AICc AICcWt Cum.Wt       LL
Mod5  9 3660.98       0.00   0.87   0.87 -1821.37
Mod1 16 3664.81       3.84   0.13   1.00 -1816.04
Mod3  8 4034.50     373.53   0.00   1.00 -2009.15
Mod2  9 4036.55     375.57   0.00   1.00 -2009.15
Mod6  9 4036.55     375.57   0.00   1.00 -2009.15
Mod4 10 4064.09     403.11   0.00   1.00 -2021.90
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think I have figured it out. None of these models are right. `mod 5` is the closest, but I think I need to include the pictures in the nesting to actually take care of the pseudoreplication, as: lmer(thickness~treatment*time+(1|treatment:animal:photo)+(1|time:animal:photo), data = intestine). There's a similar example in Crawley's 2012 book p. 703, but here I decided to have just two random effects, instead of four, as he recommends. I think it does the job decently and agrees with diagnostic plots too.

Comment: how many measurements are you obtaining from each photo?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @NathanDay. I have just one measurement per photo.

Comment: My novice understanding of random effects models, uses the random effects to represent sub population sources in your larger sample. So for your case it seems like only `animal` is really doing this. Since each treatment has multiple animals in them and each animal can only receive one treatment I think you mod3 is the best `thickness~treatment*time+(1|animal)`.  I always find myself trying to fit the "best" model based on parameter results, but then when it comes time to explain it in a write up I realize that maybe it's not the easiest to understand. Just my two cents

Comment: Yes, actually I kind of changed my mind afterwards. I think you're right that only `animal` does the job and `photo`shouldn't be included. But I think the treatments also need to be included in the random effect to nest animal into them. So `mod5` is the best. I also don't like much using model selection to determine the random effects

Comment: One other thing I just thought of, since you only have 5 animals in each group it is right on the boarder line of treating them as random effects. Because it will be hard to accurately estimate error terms for that sub population with only 5 data points. Might want to check what happens if you simply include `animal ` as a fixed effect

Comment: That's also true @NathanDay. For this experiment we have only 5 animals, but for another response variable we have 6. Anyway it's at the border line. I'll check that.